# Try to installing git on pipenv

Tags: git, pipenv

I'd like to install ERP software and I want to install it using pipenv as package management. First of all the dependencies is listed in odoo github and I'd like to copy it to my computer. Apparently I don't have git so I tried to install it using `pipenv install git` but return this,

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for git

I could install git in the global but I tried to avoid this way since I want to isolate everything. Is there another way to make this works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Git is not Python software. It makes no sense to install it with Pipenv. Conda, maybe, but not pipenv,

Comment: Thanks for the answer @muru, I thought every packages can be install using pipenv, doesn't know that there's a limitation.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question @N0rbert, muru question is what I need